# Convert multiple recursive video files using "find" and "avconv"

Tags: bash, avconv

For converting MOV files to mp4 in the directory, I was using (I use more commands with avconv, but I shortened for syntetize):

```
for f in *.MOV; do echo "Converting $f"; avconv -i "$f" "${f:0: -4}.mp4"; done
```

And it works. It converts every file.

But now, I want to convert all the files in the directory and all subdirs (recursivelly). I tried:

```
for f in "$(find ./ -name '*.MOV')"; do echo "Converting $f"; avconv -i "$f" "${f:0: -4}.mp4"; done
```

But it doesn't work, because it outputs:

```
mario@circo3d:~/Imágenes$ for f in "$(find ./ -name '*.MOV')"; do echo "Converting $f"; avconv -i "$f" "${f:0: -4}.mp4"; done
Converting ./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9219.MOV
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9196.MOV
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9199.MOV
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9200.MOV
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9219.MOV
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9196.MOV
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9199.MOV
mario@circo3d:~/Imágenes$
```

(Last file list appear in red)

It seems that *find* works, it enters in every dir and *echo "Converting $f"* too... but avconv receives all that filenames as a list with newlines, not each one element from the "for" loop.

Why *echo* works and *avconv* doesn't?

Or...

Why *for f in *.MOV'* works with avconv and *for f in "$(find ./ -name '*.MOV')* doesn't?

Comment: What do you get if you say `for f in "$(find ./ -name '*.MOV')"; do echo "$f"; done`? That is, is it "finding" all the files -and just all of them- you want to process?

Comment: I get the list of files.MOV that are in the dir and subdirs. All and just the files I want to process. Like:

./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9219.MOV
./2015-05-23 Tutorial Masa de colores/MVI_9196.MOV
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you put them in quotes. In POSIX a newline character can very well be present in the name of the file.

The easiest solution for you would be to rewrite using `-exec` attribute of find:

```
find . -name "*.MTS" -exec echo {}  \; -exec avconv -i {} {}.mp4 \;
```

Or even better, you could use `-execdir` for the `avconv` line, it will execute the command from the directory where the file is found.

---

From your comment i see that you are having difficulty seeing where the newlines are coming from at all. So

From man page of find:

```
If no expression is given, the  expression  -print  is  used
```

and

```
-print True; print the full file name on the standard output,  followed
       by  a  newline.
```

So find actually prints all the newline characters for you. You are calling it via `$(find ...)` and then you place it in quotes, which means that all the newline characters are preserved as a regular character.

This is why your for loop executes only once.

If you absolutely must use a loop, rather than using `find`'s own execution, you probably want to use a while loop:

```
find . -name "*.MTS" | while read f; do echo "Converting $f"; avconv -i "$f" "${f:0: -4}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: Three things: 1.- This is a different technique. I would like to know why mine is not working. 2.- Why you are saying "newline character"... while my files don't have newlines? (they only have spaces) 3.-  With this technique, how  do I get the file name without extension? Like "${f:0: -4}.mp4".

Comment: @MarioMey I have edited the answer providing some information on where the newline came from. I have also provided you with a way to do this in a different loop (a while loop)

Comment: Now I understand where the newline was. But it is so complex for me to understand these... kind of filename stuff... I'll better go back to my work. The while loop works great, only a semicolon is missing before "done". From now, I'll use this sentence. I added some codec options and _gvfs-trash_ to remove the file. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

I use sox to convert mp3 to alaw files. Very similar case. Using simple bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find . -name '*.mp3')
do
    echo $file
    sox $file -t al -c 1 -r 8000 $(echo "$file" | sed -r 's|.mp3|.alaw|g')
done
```